# Is there a way to force a WrapPanel to insert a "newline" in WPF?

Tags: wpf

If I am inserting elements into a wrap panel and there is still space in the panel before it overflows on the next line, can I specifically make it wrap over so that the subsequent elements are on the next line?

I am looking for something like this:

```
<WrapPanel>
  <Element/>
  <Element/>

  <NewLine???/>

  <Element/>
  <Element/>
  <Element/>
</WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This works:

```
<WrapPanel>
    <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>3</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>4</TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Width="10000" Height="0" />

    <TextBlock>5</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>6</TextBlock>
</WrapPanel>
```

I have to add though... this is pretty much a hack. You might want to consider using a StackPanel, and inside of that, have a WrapPanel with the items you want to Wrap... Example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>4</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
    <WrapPanel>
        <TextBlock>5</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock>6</TextBlock>
    </WrapPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: What can we do when using binding to all textBlocks?

Comment: Hmm, you should ask a new question and maybe reference this one for context. The answers may be long and require code samples, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3587172/3797778

Just add:

```
<TextBlock Text="&#xD;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could just add a Margin to the control that is to be on the new line:

```
<TextBlock Margin="0,20,0,0">5</TextBlock>
```