# How to make WrapPanel items line by line?

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

I have `WrapPanel` with icons.
I want to create it line by line (5 items per line).

So, my code:

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Grid.Column="4"
        x:Name="wpIcons">
</WrapPanel>


foreach(var ic in obj.Icons)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ic.image);
    bi.EndInit();

    Image im = new Image();
    im.Source = bi;
    wpIcons.Children.Add(im);
}
```

So, it works but not line by line.

How to make icons line by line?

Comment: Why not using a Stackpanel instead? And you should have a look at the MVVM pattern. Adding items in the code behind is far from good.

Comment: what do you mean by line by line? Is it verically or horizontally?

Comment: "5 items per line" requirement may range from easy (limiting width of `WrapPanel`, vertical stackpanel with horizontal stackpanels as items or just a pure `UniformGrid`?) to [hard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9770590/1997232) (creating own panel), depends on what exactly you want to achieve. In given code you can just try to limit `im.Width`, so that only `5` images will fit and then `6th` will be wrapped, but what should happens if window is resized, etc. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Equivalent to 'FlowBreak' property for WPF WrapPanel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403620/equivalent-to-flowbreak-property-for-wpf-wrappanel)

Answer (score 1):

If you want 5 items per line you could specify a fixed width of the `Image` elements and the `WrapPanel`:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="wpIcons" Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Grid.Column="4"
            Width="100">
</WrapPanel>
```

---

```
foreach (var ic in obj.Icons)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ic.image);
    bi.EndInit();

    Image im = new Image();
    im.Width = 20; //<-- = 100 / 5
    im.Source = bi;
    wpIcons.Children.Add(im);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have control on how many items are on a single I suggest you to use **UniformGrid**.
Here is an example:

```
  <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="2" Name="uniformGrid1" >
            <Image Source="pic1.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="pic2.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="pic3.jpg"></Image>
            <Image Source="pic4.jpg"></Image>
  </UniformGrid>
```

In the given example the pictures will be displayed on 2 rows, and 2 columns (in your case you could set Rows="5" without setting the columns). You could modify the Columns and/or rows as you wish.